# Communicate between Angular components using services

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have 2 components: home and devis. the goal is to transfer data constructed through a form and encapsulated in a variable 'this.concaInput' from devis to home component using a service. The problem is that when i try to display the variable in home i got nothing (the transfered data ..) in the code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoModel } from '../interfaces/TodoModel';
import { DevisDataService } from '../devis-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-devis',
  templateUrl: './devis.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./devis.component.css']
})
export class DevisComponent {
Nom!:string;
Prenom!:string;
Tel!:string;
Email!:string;
Ville!:string;  
newdevisText!: string;
cuisineType!: string;
concaInput!:String;
isChecked!: boolean;



constructor(private dataService: DevisDataService){}



concatenateFormInput():void{
  this.concaInput = this.Nom + " " + this.Prenom + "\n" + this.Tel + " " + this.Email + "\n" +           this.cuisineType + "\n" + this.newdevisText 
  const variableToTransfer = 'Your data to transfer';

  this.dataService.setSharedData(variableToTransfer);
  console.log(this.concaInput)
```

}

}

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoModel } from '../interfaces/TodoModel';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DevisDataService } from '../devis-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'MyAppAE';
  @Input("NewText")
  newTodoText!: string;
  todoList: TodoModel[] = [];
  displayDate!: string;
  receivedData: any;



  constructor(private dataService: DevisDataService){}



  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // Get the current date
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var dayOfMonth = currentDate.getDate();
    var dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
    var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var monthOfyear = currentDate.getMonth();
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    this.displayDate = daysOfWeek[dayOfWeek] + ', ' + dayOfMonth + ' ' + months[monthOfyear];
    // The 'home' component is listening for changes in the 'messenger'
    this.dataService.sharedData$.subscribe((data) => {
    this.receivedData = data;
    console.log('the tranfered data: ',this.receivedData)

    }
    );
   } 
  }


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DevisDataService {


  constructor() { }

  private sharedDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  sharedData$ = this.sharedDataSubject.asObservable();

  setSharedData(data: any) {
    this.sharedDataSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

I tried the code above and expected to get the results displayed in the home component's template. this what i tried.

Comment: please share your service file

Comment: Which is the place inside the DevisComponent where you are executing your concatenateFormInput() method?

Comment: the concatenateFormInput() is used in the template html of the DevisComponent (devis.component.html): the template is form where the user enter the necessary infos and with a click event the function is triggered:     <button class="plus-button" (click)="concatenateFormInput()">Envoyer</button>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
export class DevisComponent {
   concaInput: string;
   constructor(private dataService: DevisDataService){}

   concatenateFormInput():void{
      const variableToTransfer = 'Your data to transfer';
      this.dataService.setSharedData(variableToTransfer);
      console.log(this.concaInput)
    }
}


export class HomeComponent {
   receivedData: string;
   constructor(private dataService: DevisDataService){}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.dataService.sharedData$.subscribe((data)= > {
         console.log(data) // your data here
      })
   }
}



export class DevisDataService {
   sharedData$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

   setSharedData(data) {
      this.sharedData$.next(data);
   }
}
```